# Passing two arrays to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a requirement in my .net project to store arrays into the database using a stored procedure. I googled on net but ended in confusion. There are some tut.s like [This](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm) and a concept called table-valued parameters. I want to insert these two arrays into a table with respective values.

My two arrays will look like:

```
stop={Hydrabad, Banglore, Chennai}
```

and

```
time={15:00, 00:11, 4:45}
```

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[InsertRoutes] 
    @RouteNo nvarchar(10),
    @RouteName nvarchar(30),
    @StartingTime time(7),
    @MorningCollege time(7),
    @EveningCollege time(7),
    @Stop nvarchar(200),
    @Time nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into tbl_Routes([RouteNo], [RouteName], [StartingTime],  
                           [MorningToCollege], [EveningFromCollege])
    values(@RouteNo, @RouteName, @StartingTime,
           @MorningCollege, @EveningCollege)
END
```

And the stop, time should be inserted into another table `tbl_stops`.

I am not not that much pro in sql please some body suggest good tutorials, or working code

**Update** Anyways i could set my self with saving one array to a column by using dbo.split like

```
       insert into tbl_Stop(RouteName)
       select DATA from dbo.Split('1212,323,34532',',')
```

But i could not go further to insert into two columns like:

```
       insert into tbl_stop(RouteName,Stop)
       ................................
       ................................
```

What to write in above empty???

Comment: There are at least a half-a-dozen different major ways to "*store an array in a database*".  You'll have to give us some clue what your confusion and/or problem was with those articles you've read on the internet, or more concrete data requirements.

Comment: i just want to pass the two array's values into respective two columns. Those articles not helping me with tis.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided contains various ways to pass arrays to stored procedure and process them. If you follow that tutorial properly, you can solve your problem.

However you can go through [this article](http://nilthakkar.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-pass-multiple-records-to-stored.html) which shows how to insert multiple values (array) in table using stored procedure.

Table Valued Parameter is one more option from Sql Server 2008 onwards. Check out [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/) tutorial that explains TVP. [This](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bursteg/2007/12/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters/) tutorial shows how to use TVP with asp.net.